# "Can not merge type" error when merging pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pdf1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7], dtype=int),
    'name': np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', None, 'e'], dtype=str)
    })
print(pdf1.dtypes)

pdf2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int),
    'name': np.array(['k', 'l', 'm', 'm', 'o', None], dtype=str)
    })
print(pdf2.dtypes)

res_pdf = pdf1.join(pdf2, on = ['id'], how = 'outer', lsuffix="_x", rsuffix="_y",)
print(res_pdf)
```

results in

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_8156/3197760477.py in <module>
     17 
     18 res_pdf = pdf1.join(pdf2, on = ['id'], how = 'outer', lsuffix="_x", rsuffix="_y",)
---> 19 spark.createDataFrame(res_pdf).show()

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    671         if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pandas.DataFrame):
    672             # Create a DataFrame from pandas DataFrame.
--> 673             return super(SparkSession, self).createDataFrame(
    674                 data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    675         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.py in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    298                     raise
    299         data = self._convert_from_pandas(data, schema, timezone)
--> 300         return self._create_dataframe(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    301 
    302     def _convert_from_pandas(self, pdf, schema, timezone):

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in _create_dataframe(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    698             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    699         else:
--> 700             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
    701         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    702         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    510 
    511         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 512             struct = self._inferSchemaFromList(data, names=schema)
    513             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    514             data = map(converter, data)

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py in _inferSchemaFromList(self, data, names)
    437         if not data:
    438             raise ValueError("can not infer schema from empty dataset")
--> 439         schema = reduce(_merge_type, (_infer_schema(row, names) for row in data))
    440         if _has_nulltype(schema):
    441             raise ValueError("Some of types cannot be determined after inferring")

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py in _merge_type(a, b, name)
   1105     if isinstance(a, StructType):
   1106         nfs = dict((f.name, f.dataType) for f in b.fields)
-> 1107         fields = [StructField(f.name, _merge_type(f.dataType, nfs.get(f.name, NullType()),
   1108                                                   name=new_name(f.name)))
   1109                   for f in a.fields]

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1105     if isinstance(a, StructType):
   1106         nfs = dict((f.name, f.dataType) for f in b.fields)
-> 1107         fields = [StructField(f.name, _merge_type(f.dataType, nfs.get(f.name, NullType()),
   1108                                                   name=new_name(f.name)))
   1109                   for f in a.fields]

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py in _merge_type(a, b, name)
   1100     elif type(a) is not type(b):
   1101         # TODO: type cast (such as int -> long)
-> 1102         raise TypeError(new_msg("Can not merge type %s and %s" % (type(a), type(b))))
   1103 
   1104     # same type

TypeError: field name_y: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'>
```

I already specified the type explicitly, but Pandas seems to ignore it (and why it thinks that it's DoubleType?).
Any ideas what's the reason and how to fix this?

Comment: `pdf1.merge(pdf2, on = 'id', how = 'outer')` works fine for me

Comment: @user1234567890 maybe it depends on the version or something.

Answer (score 0):

When you pre-define the datatype like you have, then `None` gets interpreted as `'None'`. So it's not a proper null value.

We can fix that by doing:

```
pdf1.replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
pdf2.replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Then we can merge them:

```
df = pdf1.merge(pdf2, on='id',  how='outer')
```

It appears that pyspark doesn't like `np.nan`, since it identifies it as a `DoubleType`.

You can get around this by forcing `np.nan` to `None`

```
df.replace(np.nan, None, inplace=True)
```

---

This is the exact code and output I ran for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pdf1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7], dtype=int),
    'name': np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', None, 'e'], dtype=str)
    })
pdf2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.array([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int),
    'name': np.array(['k', 'l', 'm', 'm', 'o', None], dtype=str)
    })
pdf1.replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
pdf2.replace('None', np.nan, inplace=True)
df = pdf1.merge(pdf2, on='id',  how='outer')
df.replace(np.nan, None, inplace=True)
spark.createDataFrame(df).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+------+------+
| id|name_x|name_y|
+---+------+------+
|  1|     a|     k|
|  2|     b|     l|
|  3|     c|     m|
|  4|     d|  null|
|  6|  null|     o|
|  7|     e|  null|
|  5|  null|     m|
+---+------+------+
```

You're doing something else wrong if this still fails.

Comment: It fails in both cases.

Comment: @user626528 updated with my full exact code and output.

Comment: Looks like it's something configuration or version dependent, because the code works in Jupyter but fails in the Spark environment that we use.